# function gives different result when used inside a loop

Tags: r, function, loops

I would like to use this formula on my data but it gives me different results. I'm not sure about that it's coming from loop or function.
Any advice? 
Thanks,

Original formula and script:

```
   vol <-c(542,123,111) 
    d2elec<- c(0,1,2)
    df<- as.data.frame(cbind(vol,d2elec))

    Vp_lambda <- function(L, df) {vsum <- sum(df[df$d2elec<=L & df$d2elec>0,'vol'])
    return (1/abs(L) * vsum)
    }
```

Result:

```
Vp_lambda(2,df)
[1] 117
```

Here my formula and script:

```
vp_lambda <- function (date,dataframe) {vsum <- sum(dataframe[dataframe$days<=date & dataframe$days > 0,"length"])
return (1/abs(date)*vsum)}
```

Result:

```
 vp_lambda(1,test)
[1] 4901
```

When I run this function into loop, it gives different results:

```
for (i in test){
  test$absolute<-vp_lambda(test$days,test)
}
```

Result:

```
test[1,4]
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

  absolute
     (dbl)
1   278845
```

My data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:31, .Label = c("2015-05-08", 
"2015-05-09", "2015-05-10", "2015-05-11", "2015-05-12", "2015-05-13", 
"2015-05-14", "2015-05-15", "2015-05-16", "2015-05-17", "2015-05-18", 
"2015-05-19", "2015-05-20", "2015-05-21", "2015-05-22", "2015-05-23", 
"2015-05-24", "2015-05-25", "2015-05-26", "2015-05-27", "2015-05-28", 
"2015-05-29", "2015-05-30", "2015-05-31", "2015-06-01", "2015-06-02", 
"2015-06-03", "2015-06-04", "2015-06-05", "2015-06-06", "2015-06-07"
), class = "factor"), length = c(4901L, 5889L, 5314L, 3328L, 
2688L, 1447L, 2003L, 1300L, 1671L, 1415L, 4545L, 7415L, 6319L, 
7622L, 6300L, 8464L, 12466L, 6538L, 7737L, 8244L, 9089L, 6276L, 
9804L, 8551L, 5763L, 6713L, 10850L, 14673L, 28028L, 19956L, 53536L
), days = 1:31, absolute = c(278845, 139422.5, 92948.3333333333, 
69711.25, 55769, 46474.1666666667, 39835, 34855.625, 30982.7777777778, 
27884.5, 25349.5454545455, 23237.0833333333, 21449.6153846154, 
19917.5, 18589.6666666667, 17427.8125, 16402.6470588235, 15491.3888888889, 
14676.0526315789, 13942.25, 13278.3333333333, 12674.7727272727, 
12123.6956521739, 11618.5416666667, 11153.8, 10724.8076923077, 
10327.5925925926, 9958.75, 9615.34482758621, 9294.83333333333, 
8995)), .Names = c("date", "length", "days", "absolute"), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Axeman for correction in title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) test$absolute[i]<-vp_lambda(test$days[i],test)
```

Right now, you supply `test$days`, which is a vector, as `date`. This messes up `dataframe$days<=date` as it evaluates to:

```
test$days <= test$days
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[13] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[25] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This is why `vsum` becomes `278845`, which is equal to `sum(test$length)`. If we plug that into `1/abs(date)*vsum`, we get back a vector of length `31` because `date` is a vector of `1:31`.

There are multiple ways to solve this (e.g. vectorization), but my guess is that you were attempting the solution I provided at the beginning, so that's the one I give. When using `for` loops, make sure that you know what `i` is (in this case a sequence of 1 to 31) and make sure that you implement `i` into the code within the `for` loop (in this case with indexing by `i`).

Comment: Thanks @Laterow for your explanation and solution.